Is OAuth Sub claim sensitive data?
I have a question about the subclaim given by Google (but also in general for other providers) authorization servers. My question is, is the sub claim considered sensitive data? (Just the sub claim, no others) Can it be shared/stored from a privacy point of view? I couldn't find relevant literature about it.

In short - yes - it can be sensitive. Exact details might depend on your identity system:

It is sometimes a username that reveals personally identifiable information (PII).

Even if it is a UUID it might enable user tracking in non-obvious ways.


There is an OAuth-related concept called Pairwise Pseudonymous Identifier (PPID) that you might look into, which enables distinct subject claims per OAuth client (or set of related clients).
